Django /media/ files not served in production on hosting
I really feel like I am stuck, and hosting support doesn't include configuration help so maybe someone here would know.
I have django server with model:
class Video(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails/', blank=True, null=True) 

Saved here in folder thumbnails:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/username/domains/domain.com/djangoapp/media'

When I later want to use uploaded image in html:
<img src="{{ video.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ video.title }}" class="video-thumbnail">

it it not served in production (works on debug=True), file not found 404
File is correctly uploaded, but not served
I did python3 manage.py collectstatic
enter image description here
with no results.
Here's the .htaccess file in the domain folder:
enter image description here
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/username/domains/domain.com/djangoapp"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/username/virtualenv/domains/domain.com/djangoapp/3.7/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/media/
    RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ /home/username/domains/domain.com/djangoapp/media/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

that I tried adding this rule to, with no result.
Any ideas on what could i try? Or anybody who had similar problem?
I tried to clear database and migrate it from zero. Tried collecting static. I tried changing rule in .htaccess. I tried running in debug and it worked.

from your explanation, its happens to be from your web server
My thought, it could be a permission issue.
Ensure that the server has the necessary permissions for the media directory and files
